# Specific Database Design - Multiple rows vs Multiple Columns

Tags: database

This question is very specific, please answer accordingly with your views from speed, normalization concepts and table maintenance perspective.

I am designing a social networking site where I need to store friendship information. I have designed table containing auto_increment_integer id, userId1 (int) and userId2 (int). For storing each friendship I can have two options:

1. Add one entry per friendship
2. Add two entries with id1_val, id2_val and id2_val, id1_val

First option has an advantage as less number of rows need to be stored (i.e. only one per friendship) whereas second approach gives faster searching as search query contains only one column. With indexed userId1 column, searching becomes faster.

Can anyone suggest any other advantage / disadvantage with any of the above approach ?

Comment: Is it anticipated that any further information will be added that specifically relates to this friendship?

Comment: Don't think so. Friends can be sorted based on added recently but that can be done by sorting the list based on auto increment id desc